# preg_match not distinguish Latin and Cyrillic characters

Tags: php

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L}\s]+$/u', 'АБВГД ENGLISH STRING', $matches);
```

here it matches all the characters Cyrillic and Latin, why they are not filtered?, the file encoding is utf-8, what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: Because `preg_match` performs match, not filtering. I suppose you need `preg_replace` instead

Comment: I mean the matches are in $matches variable, I need to get only the latin characters match, the modifier {L} means only the Latin characters, but this don't work and I can't understand why

Comment: @yeahitsme: No, `\p{L}` means *any letter*. The code works as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

`/^(?:\p{Cyrillic}+|\p{Latin}+)$/`,  Do grouping to allow only one type of char.

`\p{Cyrillic}`,  it matches any cyrillic character..

`\p{Latin}`,  it matches any latin character.

if you need only English Characters in whole string:

use:

```
preg_match_all('/[\p{Latin}]+/u', 'АБВГД ENGLISH STRING', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It will return all english matches.

Comment: hmmm if I have in the string cyrillic and lating characters, i get no matches, can I get only the english even if there are cyrillic in the string?

Answer (score 1):

`\p{L}` in RegEx matches Unicode Category (L is the category Letter).
That's why your regex matches all letter symbols, include cyrillic.

If you want to get just latin, use `\p{Latin}` for all unicode latin symbols, or `a-z` to match just ASCII symbols

Comment: hmmm if I have in the string cyrillic and lating characters, i get no matches, can I get only the english even if there are cyrillic in the string?

Comment: Show me your new regex

Comment: preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}\s]+$/u', 'АБВГД English', $matches)

Comment: preg_match('/[\p{Latin}\s]+/u